# Talkback does not read all fragments in ViewPager, only the first one

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, talkback

I'm working with accessibility using Talkback. I implemented a view using ViewPager and Fragments. The problem is that Talkback only reads the first fragment and does not read subsequent fragments; Does anyone have any idea how to get him to read the other fragments?

I based my implementation on this documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide

Gratitude!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.